# Lazy <option> loading

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, visibility

Assuming I have a select like this:

```
<select size="4">
  <option id="1">Please wait ...</option>
  <option id="2">Please wait ...</option>
  <option id="3">Please wait ...</option>
  <option id="4">Please wait ...</option>
  <option id="5">Please wait ...</option>
</select>
```

I should see a List of 4 elements having a scrollbar on the right.

What i like to do now is to load the text via ajax if the option becomes visible somehow (scrolling and/or initial).

### EDIT:

At the end, I do not load them lazy because of the huge metadata transfer. This is the request I must upload (send to the server):

[image: huge upload for small download]

This is inacceptable for the lazy-load of single elements.

Comment: you can easily pull data into <select><option> tag's via JSON and / or Ajax, but to get your stable scroll; you'd likely have to convert your <select><option>'s to <ul><li> with JS.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry for my bad English, but as I'm understanding this question I can present this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').on('scroll', function(){
    var sel = $(this);
    var lasto = sel.find('option:last');
    var s = sel.position().top + sel.height();
    var o = lasto.height() + lasto.position().top - 4;
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(o < s){console.log('We need AJAX!');}
    }, 2200);
  });
});
```

[Link](http://jsbin.com/jeyudol/1/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you do it:

It will only load when the element is visible.

```js
function loadSelect() {
  elementsDisplayed = Math.ceil(($(this).scrollTop() + Number($(this).css("padding-top").slice(0,-2))) / $(this).find("option:first").height() + parseFloat($(this).attr("size")));

  $(this).find("option").slice(0,elementsDisplayed).not(".loaded").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("loaded"); //prevents spam reloading certain elements

    /*$.post("fetch.php", {
              dataId : $(this).attr("id")
          }, function (data) {
              //Yay, we are now loaded
          });*/

    console.log("Loading : " + $(this).attr("id"));
  });
}

$("select").on("scroll", loadSelect);

loadSelect.bind($("select"))();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="4" style="padding:14px">
  <option id="1">Please wait ...</option>
  <option id="2">Please wait ...</option>
  <option id="3">Please wait ...</option>
  <option id="4">Please wait ...</option>
  <option id="5">Please wait ...</option>
  <option id="6">Please wait ...</option>
  <option id="7">Please wait ...</option>
  <option id="8">Please wait ...</option>
  <option id="9">Please wait ...</option>
  <option id="10">Please wait ...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: 1. Those, who are visible at start are not loaded without scrolling. 2. They load one element ahead.

Comment: 1.  I fixed that in the new version.  2.  I think it makes more sense to load one ahead then potentially one behind...  Technically, the code loads any visible and partially visible elements.

Comment: If you don't want it to load "one ahead" I can update the code to use Math.floor rather than Math.ceil

Comment: You mean size="4" shows the 5th partitial? This would be a bug.

Comment: Ok, but if I set the select's padding to 14px, i can see the 5th who is not yet loaded

Comment: Why are you setting the padding on a select object?  You should have a containing div and set the padding on that...

Comment: a div around having the padding is like margin to the select. thats not what i like to have.

Comment: I updated the code, it now works: https://jsfiddle.net/nfnneil/25k7dyru/4/

Comment: Ok, next problem, it does not work if option is `float:left`

Comment: I've given you a great leaping off point.  This is my final answer.  And you should have made those specifications clear in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the element/option to below funtion to check if the element is visible and to execute your AJAX function call.

```
function isVisible(element) {
  var bx = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  var viewh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
  return !(bx.bottom < 0 || bx.top - viewHeight >= 0);
}
```

Execution will be like

```
if(isVisible(document.getElementById("select_id")))
{
/* Execute your ajax call here */
}
```

Comment: Thies must be called but i like to register a handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ivan0013/qk3k4sky/5/). It doesn't really use a select. It recreates its behaviour using JS. You should try out of jsfiddle since it has problem with http requests.

The handling for the ajax loaded elements is not working yet, it is easy to fix.

```js
function loadMoreItems() {
  var requestStr = "http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php";
  alert("load triggered")
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: requestStr,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'RandomWordComplete'
  });
};

function RandomWordComplete(data) {
  var op = $("li.option.last")
  op.removeClass("last")
  var li = $("<li>"+data.Word+"</li>")
  li.addClass("option")
  li.addClass("last")
  li.data("value", op.data("value") + 1)
  $("#select").append(li)
  li.slideDown()
}

$("document").ready(function() {
  $(".option").click(function() {
    $(".option").slideDown();
  });

  $(".option:not(.selected)").click(function() {
    $(".option:not(.selected)").slideUp();

    $(".option.selected").text($(this).text())
    $("#selectVal").val($(this).data("value"))
  });

  $("#select").scroll(function() {
    var div = $(this);
    if (div[0].scrollHeight - div.scrollTop() == div.height()) {
      loadMoreItems();
    }

  });
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none
}

.option {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px 0
}

.option:first-child {
  display: block
}

.option:not(.selected):hover {
  background: red
}

#select {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-height: 60px;
  overflow: auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="select">
  <li class="option selected">--</li>
  <li class="option" data-value="0">Spain</li>
  <li class="option last" data-value="1">Portugal</li>

</ul>
<input id="selectVal" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Comment: Ok, but its not an option-tag.

Comment: I know. But the behavior is similar and much more customizable than a tipical select

Comment: another option is using a plugin. You have the solution explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32094259/2127296

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work for you, it basically just checks the option's offsets, but also makes sure you're not sending multiple ajax requests

```
$(function () {

  var api = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
  var url = api + '/posts/1'

  var select = $('select')
  var option = select.find('option')
  var selectTop = select.offset().top
  var selectHeight = select.height()
  var inview, optionTop

  select.on('scroll', function () {
    option.each(function () {

      var _this = $(this)

      optionTop = _this.offset().top
      inview = optionTop >= selectTop && optionTop < selectTop + selectHeight

      // check that the option element is in range
      if (inview) {

        // don't send multiple requests if already triggered
        if (
          _this.attr('data-status') !== 'success'
          && _this.attr('data-status') !== 'loading'
          && _this.attr('data-status') !== 'error'
        ) {
          _this.attr('data-status', 'loading')
          _this.text('Loading ...')
          $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'GET',
            success: function ajaxSuccess(resp) {
              _this.attr('data-status', 'success')
              _this.text(resp.title)
            },
            error: function ajaxError(xhr) {
              _this.attr('data-status', 'error')
              _this.text('Error ...')
              console.log(xhr.responseText)
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
  })

  // bootstrap
  select.triggerHandler('scroll')
})
```

see the [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0edzbgy1/3/), it loads kind of fast, you could comment out the `triggerHandler` to prevent it sending requests on page load

**edit**: also i updated the ids of the option elements since ids shouldn't start with a number