# create dynamic select box through ajax with large data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter and ajax. There are two select boxes like country and    states.I am appending options to states select box based on country, through ajax request.
It works fine for few hundreds of records.
But When number of records exceed 1000, ajax take too much time to create select box, even page goes to not responding state.
I am using this code:

```
    var country_id = $(selector).val();
        $.ajax({

            url:'<?php echo base_url()?>getstates',
            crossDomain: true,
            data:'country_id ='+country_id ,

            success:function(data){
              var dataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
               $(dataObj).each(function(){
                        // Remove options 
                          $('#selectBoxState').find('option').not(':first').remove();

                          // Add options
                          $.each(dataObj,function(index,data){
                             $('#selectBoxState').append('<option value="'+data['state_id']+'">'+data['state_name']+'</option>');
                          });


                    });

                },
                error: function() {
                        alert("failure");

                    }
                });
```

What will be the best way to do so.

Comment: did you clear the state select box on each county change ?

Comment: yes I make it empty on each country change.

Comment: But when records exceed 1000 then it take too much time and goes to not responding state

Comment: ok. i think you can implement lazyloading. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42613043/3698937 refer this link.. i think it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Here are my working solutions for **CodeIgniter 3.x**

Controller Page

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Controller_name extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();     
    }     

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load-helper('dropdown');
        $dropdownItems = listData('countryTableName','countryId', 'countryName',['where' => ['countryStatus' => 1]]);
        $selected = array('null');
        $data['countryDropdown'] = form_dropdown('countryId',$dropdownItems,$selected);
        $data['stateDropdown'] =   form_dropdown('stateId',[], '', 'required="required"');
        $this->load->view('page_view',$data);
    }

public function get_state()
{
    $countryId = $this->input->get('countryId');
    $dropdownItems = listData('stateTableName','stateId', 'stateName',['where' => ['countryId' => $countryId,'stateStatus' => 1]]);
    $selected = array('null');
    echo $stateDropdown =   form_dropdown('stateId',$dropdownItems,$selected);
}

}
```

Place this dropdown_helper.php in Helper directory

```
<?php
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


  function listData($table,$name,$value,$options = []) {
      $items = array();
      $CI =& get_instance();
      if(array_key_exists('where',$options)) {
          $CI->db->where($options['where']);
      }
      $query = $CI->db->select("$name,$value")->from($table)->get();
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
          foreach($query->result() as $data) {
              $items[$data->$name] = $data->$value;
          }
          $default = array('null' => 'Please Select');
          $select = $default + $items;          
          $query->free_result();
          return $select;
      }
  }
```

In view page just echo

```
<?php echo $countryDropdown; ?>
<?php echo $stateDropdown; ?>
```

js file

```
$(function(){
    $('select[name=countryId]').on('change',function(){
        $('select[name=stateId]').html('');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'controller_name/get_state?countryId='+$(this).val(),
            type: "GET",
         }).done(function(data) {
            $('select[name=stateId]').html(data);
         }).fail(function() {

         }).always(function() {

        });
    });
});
```