# Infinite scroll JQuery in input tag or select tag getting issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have searched whole web, Can anyone please tell me like how to implement infinite scrolling on combo-box or any other alternatives.

i just want to have infinite scroll to be implemented in drop-down, i have tried several methods but not able to get it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<Select> widget with infinite scroll dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884192/select-widget-with-infinite-scroll-dropdown)

Comment: @NadirLaskar not working

Comment: Have a try here: https://jsfiddle.net/CD4mm/16/

 is this how you want it?

Comment: @HEGDE i want to implement something like this https://www.obout.com/combobox/aspnet_ondemand_virtual_scroll.aspx

and not getting idea like how to do that

Comment: OK @SandeepGupta , If are using jquery and ajax to bind data here is the sample: https://jsfiddle.net/2zg0m8m4/2/

Comment: @HEGDE Actually this is not the requirement. What we want is like https://www.obout.com/combobox/aspnet_ondemand_virtual_scroll.aspx

In this link it has a drop-down that is loading on demand and our requirement is like this only.

Comment: That is an ASPX telerik control.
Here you can get code for that : http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: @HEGDE can u tell me like by using jquery and ajax

Comment: As i commented above, in js-fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2zg0m8m4/2/ ,

use ajax post call to get data which you want to bind to dropdown,
then append those values

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
    .scroll-container {
        /* different behaviour can be defined for vertical/horizontal scroll*/
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: auto;
        /*adjust this according to your needs*/
        width: 73px;
        height: 70px;
    }

    .scroll-container select {
        border: none;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="scroll-container">
    <select size="10" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="1" selected>option 1</option>
     <option value="2">option 2</option>
     <option value="3">option 3</option>
     <option value="4">option 4</option>
     <option value="5">option 5 </option>
     <option value="6">option 6</option>
     <option value="6">option 7</option>
     <option value="6">option 8</option>
     <option value="6">option 9</option>
     <option value="6">option 10</option>
    </select>
</div>
```