# HTML Dropdown Menu very slow to load

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a project for a client to make their roster viewing and entry paper-free. Some things rely on user input, but others are varied constants and are pulled from a database. One of the dropdowns pulling its information from said database is loading very slowly in my testing environment - I click it, and it takes two to three seconds for the items to actually show up.

I assume this is because the dropdown contains easily close to 400 items. What I'd like to know is if there is any way I can optimize this to make the loading faster. Cutting off at halfway or even a fourth of the way and making more dropdowns is outside of specification for the project, so a suggestion like that would have to go through the client for the go ahead. If that's the only solution, though, I'll do that.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

EDIT:

1. This is the kind of oversight that makes me laugh, but I was wrong about my conservative estimate of 400 items - the list contains 12,700 items.
2. For all who assume the SQL query may be slow - I am doing a simple SELECT DISTINCT from one table, with only one WHERE condition.

Comment: You need to provide far more details, if you'd like to get meaningful help. But first, measure where the time is actually spent.. 400 is not a huge number, so there ought to be some way to speed things up..

Comment: As @xs0 said, please enter some code demonstrating how you're populating the dropdown. Based on the question, I'm assuming you're making a request to the server on dropdown open, which is going to take time. It would be better to prefetch the results and store it in the DOM

Comment: Additionally, while 400 items sounds like a lot, in terms of the performance of a browser dropdown that _really_ barely matters. Look at this fiddle for a basic demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/zv03dkym/

Answer (score 1):

Before this question can be answered well, you'll need to do more testing and debugging to figure out what exactly is slowing things down.

- Is this just a problem with your machine running something slowly?
  Test things out on a real webserver and see how things go.
- Is the select from the database slow? If so, that's a problem,
  selects from mysql should be really fast.
- Is the php slow? If so, you can use an IDE like PhpStorm to see
  exactly what functions take how long to run.
- Is the rendering in the client browser slow? If so, we can look at
  optimizing the javascript/html.

As noted in a comment above, we also need to know when you are getting data from the database (before the page loads, or ajax). So before you can really look at *how* to speed this up, you need to know *what* is taking so long. Start there. Also make sure to check your javascript and html for any errors. Copy/paste the entire page's html into here, and fix all errors and warnings: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input  For javascript, check the debugger console.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an infinite scroll to break up the amount of data being returned. Take a look at this answer:

[infinite scroll select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884192/select-widget-with-infinite-scroll-dropdown)

This may not be the underlying issue though. I would check the performance of your query to ensure that is not where the issue lies.